# Algorithms for reporting the progress of asynchronous function calls

Tags: c#, progress-bar, timing, system.diagnostics

What sort of algorithms are used to compute the progress of a function call?

Obviously its easy to do if you have a loop, something like:

```
 Action<Double> notifier = d => Console.WriteLine("Completed: " + d.ToString());

 Double _interval = 0.05;

 for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                int rem = default(int); 

                Math.DivRem(i, _interval, out rem);

                if (rem == 0)
                {
                    double progress = (double)i / 1000;
                    notifier(progress); 
                }
             }
```

But what about when you just have some generic delegate and you'd like to run it asynchronously but also notify another thread of its progress, and you can't gaurantee that you can straightforwardly use a for-loop? Some other straightforward ways might be:

1) Time the function first (very bad for performance though if its a long running task)

2) Store past timings of the function in a log and use that (but this doesnt necessarily take into account extra variables - cpu, memory, etc. at the specific time of the task)

However do any more advanced algorithms exist, even if only to approximate the progress?

Comment: If you can store past timings, that is the best way to do it. The CPU and Memory are constraints you will probably have too live with. Past timings are the best indicator of future performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BackgroundWorker` class has an update callback, but in answer to your question of a 'generic algorithm' for finding completion, Not really. The closest you can get is estimating based on Function Length (http://www.ndepend.com/) which will get you length in lines of code.

Comment: That's interesting, looking at lines of code. I wonder if you could use a reflection-based approach where you try to walk down a metadata tree and measure the total # of primitive operations involved, then calculate an estimate based on that.

Comment: That can probably be done using NDepend or the Program Database (pdb). The hardest part of it is getting the program stack pointer so you know where in the code it currently is... I think that C# abstracts most of that away

Answer (score 1):

Pass the worker function a callback delegate and have it report it's progress back to the UI.

The UI shouldn't be in charge of "figuring out what to do", instead it should just take updates from the worker.

For example:

```
 void longRunningFunction(Action<int> updateCallback)
 {
        // Do something long, but on measurable places, call updateCallback
        updateCallback(50);
 }
```

And in the UI:

```
longRunningFunction(x => progressBar.SetProgress(x));
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is what I've done in the past as well.

Comment: My question is more geared towards cases where for whatever reason you cannot write updateCallback() into the function, but instead have a generic Func or Action that you want to deduce the progress of as its running. For example say you have some sort of file IO function -- you can run it with a very small file, time it, and use that time to approximate how long a longer file would take.

Answer (score 1):

Is this an academic question?

If not, you could opt to use `BackgroundWorker`, which has a built in `ReportProgress` method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx

I suppose you could also use .net reflector to look at its implementation if you're curious

Comment: Does that ReportProgress method somehow calculate a percent complete figure even if you havent written any sort of timing / progress reporting into your function? If so i'd be really interested in how that works, yes.

Comment: Actually no, it doesn't. So not quite what you're looking for